# Slim3 Cannot use object of type Slim\Http\Response as array

Tags: php, jwt, slim, slim-3

I am having trouble with adding error output to the JWT middleware set up.

I am getting this error: `Cannot use object of type Slim\Http\Response as array`

I am using Slim 3 and the slim-jwt-auth package, I am using the sample code in the docs found at https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth#error

The difference being I'm calling `\Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication` instead of `Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication`. If I use that the class cannot be found. Everything was working fine until I wanted to add the error output to the middleware set up, here is my code:

```
    $app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "path" => "/mypath",
    "passthrough" => "/mypath/get-auth",
    "secret" => getenv("SKEY"),
    "secure" => false,
    "error" => function ($response, $args) {
      $data = array();
      $data["status"] = "error";
      $data["message"] = $args["message"];
      return $response
        ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        ->getBody()->write(
         json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); 
      }
    ]));
```

The error output says it's coming from the line `$data["message"] = $args["message"];`.

Am I looking right at the problem and not seeing it?

Comment: Maybe because `$args` is a `Slim\Http\Response` and not an `array`

Comment: shouldn't be the signature for "error" actually
`"error" => function ($request, $response, $args) {}`
?

Comment: @jDolba - you were right, that was the problem - thanks

Answer (score 2):

The function signature for the `"error"`  closure is:

```php
function ($request, $response, $args): Response
```

You're missing the first parameter in your code, so when you use `$args`, you're getting the `Response` object.